Respect the current "quad" when using transform.translate
I have a modal operator that calls bpy.ops.transform.translate('INVOKE_DEFAULT') as part of its code. Having written code that adjusts the position of the mouse cursor (before transform.translate is called) to be in one of the 4 quads, I was dismayed to find that the mouse position didn't matter.
Rather than moving in respect to the quad where the mouse is (the behaviour observed when using the transform tools normally), it moves it based on which quad the transform.translate tool was last triggered in.
By 'moving in respect to', I mean that if you're in the quad view that looks down on the Z axis, I expect the translate tool to move the object on the Y and Z axis. Because it ignores which quad the mouse is actually in, it makes it impossible for me to have code that dynamically switches between the 4 quads.
How can I choose which axis transform.translate uses when the 3D Viewport is in 'quad view' mode?
